# A way to Wrap LinearLayout

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been trying to find a solution for this for weeks and keep putting this on my backlist, I am unable to wrap the height of a `LinearLayout`.

I have a simple LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/tagsLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Then I am adding multiple `TextViews` using my code into that `LinearLayout` with Tags Link style

```
Txt.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.roundtext);
Txt.SetPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
Txt.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#373944"));
Txt.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 12);
```

The results are the following 
[image]

See the last TextView never goes to the next line

I looked up so many threads and solutions and it turns out that `LinearLayout` cannot Wrap contents like this Instead I will have to create my own Layout such as `FlowLayout`

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GridView` instead of `LinearLayout`.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/tagsLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>
```

This should automatically put the `TextView` to next line. If you want something more dynamic then you use [FlowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) library or [StaggeredLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager).Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android) which claims that it has alternative to FlowLayout.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, sound like a good solution but as i am adding `TextViews` such as `myGridView.AddView(TEXTVIEW)` i get error `Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException` seems like `AddView` is not supported

Comment: Used the ArrayAdapter to add items into GridView but it is not giving the desired results, it just divides textboxes to Columns.

Comment: @aliusman use custom adapter as Indicated in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107064/how-to-add-view-to-gridview-programmatically-android) or Array adapter with default Ids as shown in this [blog](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-gridview-add-item.html)

Comment: @aliusman Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240981/dynamically-add-boxviews-to-grid-xamarin-forms) for Xamarin

Comment: I used `ArrayAdapter` which works (sorta) it actually divides text into columns where i am looking for the solution like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFf2W.png

Comment: @aliusman Try to reduce the spacing to `2dp` and check if it works. But it would be still column based. Not sure you would be able to achieve your intended output.

Comment: reducing spacing gives the same results,

Comment: @aliusman Have you checked out [FlowLayout](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout) ? Looks like this library is what you want.

Comment: yeah, I mentioned in my comment that if there is another solution, other then 
 the `FlowLayout`

Comment: @aliusman You can also check out [StaggeredLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager). Sometime ago I came across this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android) which claimed it has alternative for it

Comment: that's very interesting, You should change your answer to this - I will make it accepted

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).
Easy to use and import with Gradle.

Comment: thanks for your reply, any xamarin related ideas, I found Binding android libraries in C# is so painful

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you needed a Xamarin solution and unfortunately I haven't got an answer for that.

Comment: I voted this up as I figured out that there is already a c# binding available for this. Thanks for your suggestion